# Why i can't see my objects in design at visual studio asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a asp.net page `account.aspx` in my project but I can't see my objects like my table or my butten in it.
What's the reason?
Here is some of my code which I can't see that :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="account.aspx.cs" Inherits="banktest.account" %>

    .
    .
    .
    <section class =" container">

            <!-- start Pages -->


            <div id="pages">
                <div class="top_shadow"></div>
                            <!-- Start Price -->
                <div id="price" class="page">
                <h1>حساب کاربری جدید</h1>
                <div class="tabs">

                <div id="tab_1" class="pane" style="width:100%;text-align:center"> 

               <table style="width:110%;">

                <tr>
                    <td class="style1">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="style2">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="نام" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="firstnametxt" runat="server" Height="22px" MaxLength="20" 
                            Width="158px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                  <td>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstnameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="firstnametxt"  ErrorMessage="نام خود را وارد کنید"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>              </td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="نام خانوادگی" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="lastnametxt" runat="server" Height="22px" MaxLength="10" 
                            Width="158px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                     <td>
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LastbaneRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="lastnametxt"  ErrorMessage="نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="شماره تلفن" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="phonetxt" runat="server" Height="22px" MaxLength="10" 
                            Width="158px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                     <td>
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PhoneRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="phonetxt"  ErrorMessage="شماره تلفن خود را وارد کنید." EnableViewState="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  </td>
                    <td>
                   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="ورودی نا معتبر!" ControlToValidate="phonetxt" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="style1">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="style2">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style1">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Button ID="buy" runat="server" onclick="buybtn_Click" Text="تایید و پرداخت " />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="style1">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <td><asp:Label ID="msglabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Medium" ></asp:Label></td>

                    </td>
                     <td>
                         &nbsp
                     </td>

                </tr>
            </table>  
                        &nbsp
                        &nbsp

                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Price -->
                            <div class="bottom_shadow"></div>
                </div>
             </div>
            <!-- End Pages -->


            <div class="clear"></div>


            <!-- End Pages -->  

                </section>
    .
    .
    .
```

What should i do now?
That is because of my code or visual studio